# Select data from especific user PHP using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to select data from a especific user. When he login on website he will see informations related to him.

I'm using INNER JOIN and I need to select a data related to his login or id.

Any Account that I use to login, I can access all exercises registered =/

On this case I'm using an ID.

It has something wrong on query?

I don't get any errors from PHP. Where can I put the WHERE clause?

Code:

```
<?php


  $login  = $_SESSION['login'];



  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT exercicios.nome_exercicio AS nome_exc,
   exercicios.repeticoes_exercicio AS rep_exc,
   exercicios.serie_exercicio AS serie_exc 
FROM exercicios
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuario = exercicios.id_usuario WHERE exercicios.id_usuario = '5'");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta)> 0){

       echo "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-responsive'>
         <tr><td>Nome</td><td>Repetições</td><td>Série</td></tr>";

      while ($exercicio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta))
          {



   print"<tr>

                      <td>$exercicio[nome_exc]</td> 
                      <td>$exercicio[rep_exc]</td>
                      <td>$exercicio[serie_exc]</td>


                      </tr>";






  }

        echo " </table></div>";

  }
   else {
       echo "<h3>Seu instrutor ainda não cadastrou exercícios</h3>";
   }



  ?>
```

Comment: If the query is running normally and no errors. What is the issue?

Comment: If you're accessing sessions (Eg. `$_SESSION['login']`) be sure to include `session_start();` at the top of your script/before trying to access any session variables.

Comment: I did this and nothing happens. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you check the query in PhpMyAdmin or a similar tool? Does it return all expected values? Also, check your [error_reporting settings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). You might want to set this to E_ALL to debug this.